# How to pass parameters between Multiple containers using docker-compose

Tags: java, python, networking, docker, docker-compose

Hi i am trying to understand docker compose and how to pass parameters between the containers so that i can use it in my application.

I have built a simple hello world application using two micro services

The first micro-service is using java:

```
//java code hello.java
public class hello
{
    public static void main(String args[])
   {
       System.out.println("hello world from java");
   }
}

//Dockerfile for creating this image 
FROM java:7
COPY hello.java .
RUN javac hello.java
CMD ["java","hello"]
```

Similarly for the image using python i have two files:

hello.py

```
print("hello from python")
```

Dockerfile for this image is:

```
FROM python:2.7
COPY hello.py .
CMD ["python","hello.py"]
```

my docker-compose file:

```
javacl:
  build: .
  links: pythoncl
pythoncl:
  build: ./pythonfolder
```

What i want to do is to pass parameters , which i would be taking from the user in the java program and then want to pass that parameter to the python program and then display it. It is just an example app as i am trying to understand how can i pass parameters between containers

I have seen the docker website which has a python app as an example, but any one could please use a java program and a python program and then could simply show as how to pass parameters with a very simple example.

**One solution is to pass the parameters through the network as all containers have there own network stack, but are there any alternatives for passing the parameters**.

I am new to docker and any help would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways of dealing ipc. This is just one approach by exposing port in destination container (java server) and link from the source container (python client).
I created an example for you. In this case, I am connecting from Python to Java.

My folder structure looks like this:

```
anovil@ubuntu-anovil:~/tmp/docker-ipc$ tree .
.
├── docker-compose.yml
├── javacl
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── Main.class
│   ├── Main.java
│   └── OneConnection.class
└── pythoncl
    ├── client.py
    └── Dockerfile

2 directories, 7 files
anovil@ubuntu-anovil:~/tmp/docker-ipc$
```

My Server ([source](http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-networking-tutorials/415-how-create-server-socket-listen-incoming-connections.html)) which listens and outputs what ever it gets on port 10001:

```
anovil@ubuntu-anovil:~/tmp/docker-ipc$ cat javacl/Main.java 
import java.io.*;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            final int myPort = 10001;
            ServerSocket ssock = new ServerSocket(myPort);
            System.out.println("Listening on port " + myPort );

        while (true) {
            Socket sock = ssock.accept();
            System.out.println("Someone has made socket connection");
            OneConnection client = new OneConnection(sock);
            String s = client.getRequest();
        }
    }

}

class OneConnection {
    Socket sock;
    BufferedReader in = null;
    DataOutputStream out = null;

    OneConnection(Socket sock) throws Exception {
        this.sock = sock;
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
        out = new DataOutputStream(sock.getOutputStream());
    }

    String getRequest() throws Exception {
        String s = null;
        while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("got: " + s);
        }
        return s;
    }
}

anovil@ubuntu-anovil:~/tmp/docker-ipc$
```

And my client connects to host: java-server on port: 10001 and sends "hello stackoverflow":

```
anovil@ubuntu-anovil:~/tmp/docker-ipc$ cat pythoncl/client.py 
#!/usr/bin/python
#client example
import socket
import time

print "Waiting for socket"
time.sleep(3)
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
client_socket.connect(('java-server', 10001))
client_socket.send("hello")
client_socket.send(" stackoverflow")
client_socket.close()
while 1:
  pass # do nothing
anovil@ubuntu-anovil:~/tmp/docker-ipc$
```

Each of those containers just invokes the server and client respectively, except that server exposes 10001 port for other containers and those docker files look like this:

```
anovil@ubuntu-anovil:~/tmp/docker-ipc$ cat javacl/Dockerfile 
FROM java:7

COPY Main.class OneConnection.class /

EXPOSE "10001"

CMD ["java","Main"]
anovil@ubuntu-anovil:~/tmp/docker-ipc$ cat pythoncl/Dockerfile 
FROM python:2.7

COPY client.py /client.py

CMD python client.py
anovil@ubuntu-anovil:~/tmp/docker-ipc$
```

Then in the compose file, javacl container is given a hostname to identify itself and pythoncl links to javacl like this:

```
anovil@ubuntu-anovil:~/tmp/docker-ipc$ cat docker-compose.yml 
javacl:
  build: ./javacl
  hostname: java-server  
pythoncl:
  build: ./pythoncl
  links: 
    - "javacl"
anovil@ubuntu-anovil:~/tmp/docker-ipc$
```

Now when you run it,

```
anovil@ubuntu-anovil:~/tmp/docker-ipc$ docker-compose up
Starting dockeripc_javacl_1
Starting dockeripc_pythoncl_1
Attaching to dockeripc_javacl_1, dockeripc_pythoncl_1
javacl_1   | Listening on port 10001
javacl_1   | Someone has made socket connection
javacl_1   | got: hello stackoverflow
...
```

The server and client are intentionally made to run continuously so that we can check them respectively like this:

```
anovil@ubuntu-anovil:~/tmp/docker-ipc$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
c96961f03d57        dockeripc_pythoncl   "/bin/sh -c 'python c"   13 minutes ago      Up 19 seconds                           dockeripc_pythoncl_1
9d0163aa34f5        dockeripc_javacl     "java Main"              13 minutes ago      Up 19 seconds       10001/tcp           dockeripc_javacl_1
anovil@ubuntu-anovil:~/tmp/docker-ipc$
```

One could login to those containers via `attach` or `exec` and see what happens

Comment: thanks for such a great explanation , it really helped me a lot. so For passing parameters between containers i have to use network stack , Are there any alternatives to that

Comment: You have mentioned there are many ways of doing ipc , can you please list them, so i can check the trade offs between them

Comment: 1. Alternatives: Do you see a drawback with your infrastructure in this setup. It would be good to know the problem/limitation here. 2. You might know that Ipc itself can be implemented in many ways (file, socket, pipe, semaphore, message queue etc.), I chose the socket way. However, I think I should really know your requirements in terms of setup, scalability etc. If you have a light weight Java based UI application and a single python client injecting data, then we could even go with single docker container running both the processes (no need to go at a network level opening ports).

Comment: the application is huge and there are many microservices in my application , Which could possibly be running in different hosts . Is communication between the docker containers possible using messages and queues , can you share a link where an example of such is given.

Comment: one more question , The output of the program doesn't print "waiting for socket" ,This line is written in the python program before any socket connection was made to the java server

Comment: What modifications do i need to make in the python program  if user had to give some input and then pass it to the java server,I tried to do some modifications but it's not working for me

Answer (score 0):

You can make programs from different containers communicate using the network.

What you want is to implement some sort of remote procedure call between your two programs. In the end, it is not a Docker issue.